# Best practice for comparing two method signatures

Tags: c#, memoization

I have a dictionary which stores method call results. 
The Dictionary key is the method call signature i.e.
an object with the following members.

```
string _name, 
Type[] _argTypes, 
string[] _argNames, 
object[] _argValues.
```

I must override the GetHashCode method for the TryGetValue to compare correctly.
What is the most efficient way to compare the method signatures? i.e. the 4 parameters above.

e.g. this does not seem efficient to me.

```
 public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            if(_name!=null)
                _hashCode = _name.GetHashCode();

            if (_argTypes != null)
            {
                foreach (object value in _argTypes)
                    _hashCode ^= value.GetHashCode();
            }
            if (_argNames != null)
            {
                foreach (object value in _argNames)
                    _hashCode ^= value.GetHashCode();
            }
            if (_argValues != null)
            {
                foreach (object value in _argValues)
                    _hashCode ^= value.GetHashCode();
            }
        }
```

Comment: At the very least implement GetHashCode in a recommended way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode - And have you thought about just calculating it once and then caching it?

Comment: this is called "memoization", knowing that may improve search results

Comment: Don't you need to override `Equals` as well? `GetHashCode()` is just used for uniform distribution. Once you have a hash, you need to have an `Equals` implementation that compares your method signature for equality.